# case: 'my' or 'me'?

Tags: personal-pronouns, grammatical-case

> Thank you baby for **my** being able to share this with you

or

> Thank you baby for **me** being able to share this with you

Which is correct?

Comment: http://grammar.yourdictionary.com/parts-of-speech/pronouns/types-of-pronouns.html

Comment: I have no idea what “correct” means, but native speakers use both. Just use whichever you normally say and don’t worry about it.

Comment: Although I'm not OP, but I believe this grammatical situation is still not properly resolved in this community. My paradoxical case with *"never bet against me being stupid"* was also closed ( http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/31437/me-being-versus-my-being ). So much for collective knowledge...